# How can I make `Tee-Object` not adding a trailing newline in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, newline, tee, trailing-newline, powershell-7.2

[`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.2) does not have a `-NoNewline` switch like many other output-to-file-cmdlets (e. g. [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.2), [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.2)). [Under the hood](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7dc4587014bfa22919c933607bf564f0ba53db2e/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/Tee-Object.cs#L101), `Tee-Object` uses `Out-File` to write to a file, which adds a trailing newline by default.

As I (*currently*) cannot pass through the `-NoNewline` switch through `Tee-Object`, is there another way I can enforce that the underlying `Out-File` won't add a trailing newline? Looking at the [implementation of `Out-File`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7dc4587014bfa22919c933607bf564f0ba53db2e/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/FormatAndOutput/out-file/Out-File.cs#L167), there might be now way, but maybe someone is aware of some tricks/hacks to achieve it anyway?

Some constraints:

- I want to use `Tee-Object` (or an alternative solution) in a pipeline
- I do not want to post-process the files generated by `Tee-Object` (or an alternative solution), like opening them again and removing the (last) newline.

Code for reproduction:

```
"Test" | Tee-Object file | Out-Null
```

On Windows, the generated file `file` will contain 6 bytes like shown in the following hexdump:

```
          00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F ASCII
00000000  54 65 73 74 0D 0A                               Test..
```

Which, unfortunately, contains the additional bytes `0D 0A` a. k. a. `` `r`n `` or CR&LF in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could roll your own and write a prefixed newline:

```
function Tee-StackProtectorObject {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [psobject]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        $Path,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        $LiteralPath
    )

    begin {
        # Determine newline character sequence at the start (might differ across platforms)
        $newLine = [Environment]::NewLine

        # Prepare parameter arguments for Add-Content
        $addContentParams = @{ NoNewLine = $true }
        if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Path'){
            $addContentParams['Path'] = $Path
        }
        else {
            $addContentParams['LiteralPath'] = $LiteralPath
        }
    }

    process {
        # Write to file twice - first a newline, then the content without trailling newline
        Add-Content -Value $newLine @addContentParams
        Add-Content -Value $InputObject @addContentParams

        # Write back to pipeline
        Write-Output -InputObject $InputObject
    }
}
```

Note that, unlike `Tee-Object`, the function above is in perpetual "append mode". Refactoring it to support both appending and overwriting is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Now we have a leading newline ;-) Not quite what I was asking for (I want to control the written data by myself and especially, what goes in, should go out (unmodified)), but a reimplementation is a valid solution and it can easily be adapted. Thx!